# Prove that $\forall A (A \ne P(A))$ where P(x) is the power set of x

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $\forall A ( A \ne P(A))$ where P(x) is the power set of x 
Let's assume that the assumption is false and use the axiom of extentionality: 
$$\forall x(x\in A \iff x\in P(A))$$
$$\forall x(x\in A \iff x \subseteq A)$$
$$\forall x(x\in A \iff \{x \}\in A)$$ 
Which implies that
$$\{x, \{x \} \}\in A$$
But I still can't see an obvious contradiction here.

EDIT: I've just come up with another idea to solve this:
$$\forall x(x\in A \iff x \in P(A))$$
Let's take $x = A$ 
 $A\in P(A)$ but $A \notin A$ (Russel)
Does this work?

Comment: Note that there *are* sets with the property $\forall x(x\in A\leftrightarrow \{x\}\in A)$

Comment: Russell's paradox is not that $A\in A$ is contradictory. It is the $\{A\mid A\in A\}$ cannot be a set. But thinking about Russell's paradox is a good start.

Comment: Yes, $A\notin A$ is a consequence of the Axiom of Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

A and P(A) are not equinumerous.
If they were equal, they'd be equinumerous.